# Ayuda Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: php

Estoy realizando una pagina para el colegio y tengo un problema con los comunicados. Este es el código donde esta el problema

```
      <?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['rol']=='administrador' OR isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['rol']=='Padre' OR isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['rol']=='Docente'){
     echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_d\',\'alta_co.php\')">Nuevo Comunicado</button>';
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_L\',\'mostrar_comunicados.php?b='.$_SESSION['lastname'].'&n='.$_SESSION['name'].'\')">Ver Comunicados</button>';
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary  btn-sm"   onclick="cargar(\'#capa_d\',\'mostrar_comunicados.php?a='.$_SESSION['lastname'].'&j='.$_SESSION['name'].'\')">Mis comunicados</button>';
    }
  ?>
```

Y el problema viene cuando $_SESSION['lastname'] son dos apellidos y no solo uno
, osea en ves de ser "Gutierrez" es "Gutierrez Gonzalez" el error que salta en la consola es:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Gutierrez&n=Milo
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, Gracias por cualquier ayuda.
Aqui el codigo de la función cargar

```
   <script>
   function cargar(div,desde)
   {
   $(div).load(desde);
   } 
   </script>
```

Comment: Pero esto parece ser más bien un error de Javascript que de PHP. ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_SESSION);`?  Quizá sea un problema de codificación, si el `var_dump` muestra caracteres extraños conviene que revises cómo estás manejando la codificación de caracteres en los diferentes niveles donde se origina el dato.

Comment: comparte el código de la función cargar (js)